# Executing binary/elf-file directly from (shared)-memory in C

Tags: c, gcc, binary, executable, elf

we are trying to copy a binary/elf file into a shared-memory region of our system and then execute it thereafter. We don't want to call our "client"-program directly, since we need to execute it from the memory itself for our purpose.

While we know that our approach (*described below*) won't really work, we are (*obviously*) trying to get it to work. How would it be possible to copy a binary/elf/etc. file directly into the (shared)-memory and execute it thereafter? Maybe we just compiled it in the wrong way? Or something else was done wrong?

We also don't want to convert it into hex/shell-code, we already did that. We are looking for an easier and more practical solution.

Is anyone able to help? Would be much appreciated!

**Two programs:**

1. "Host"-Program (*copy & execute client-program in shared memory*)
2. "Client"-Program (*basically a hello-world echo*)

**"Client"-Program:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `gcc -o binfile clientprogram.c -static`.

**"Host"-Program:**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  FILE *fp; //filepointer
  size_t size; //filesize
  unsigned char *buffer; //buffer

  fp = fopen("binfile","rb"); 
  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END); 
  size = ftell(fp);
  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET); 
  buffer = (unsigned char *) malloc(size);
  if (fp == NULL){ //file empty?
      printf("Error: There was an Error reading the file %s \n", "binfile");           
      exit(1);
  }
  else if (fread(buffer, sizeof *buffer, size, fp) != size){ 
      printf("Error: There was an Error reading the file %s\n", "binfile");
      exit(1);
  }else{
    int i;
    // for(i=0; i<size;i++){       
    //    printf("%02x", buffer[i]);
    // }
  }


  void *mem = mmap(0, size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
  memcpy(mem, buffer, size);
  mprotect(mem, size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC);

  void (*func)();
  func = (void (*)()) buffer;
  func();  

  munmap(mem, size);

  fclose(fp);
  free(buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `gcc hostprogram.c`.

Comment: This approach is naive and will of course fail. Loading and executing a binary is far more complicated than just reading it into memory and calling the load address. This is probably an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What _exactly_ are you trying to achieve?

Comment: While the `main` function is the official entry-point into your program, there is a lot of code being executed *before* the `main` function is called. For example initialization of global variables is handled before the `main` function, but also other things like setting up the standard file streams `stdout`, `stdin` and `stderr`. Doing that should only happen once. Not to mention that an [ELF file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) doesn't start with *code* that can be called.

Comment: As for your question, *why* do you want to do this? What problem is it supposed to solve?

Comment: @Marvin Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019923/executing-machine-code-in-memory).

Comment: Thanks for the input, MichaelWalz, Someprogrammerdude and GauravPathak! @Someprogrammerdude We want to be able to copy any (of our own) programs into a shared-memory region and then execute it from there. The approach above was just the first thing that came to our minds, we know its naive ;) Does anyone have any ideas how to do this with another approach?

Comment: But why do you need to use shared memory? Why can't you use the method described in [the answer by PSkocik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44544383/440558)? If you're worried about loading multiple copies of the program into memory, then don't worry. The operating system should only load a shared object (ELF file) once, and simply map it into the different processes that uses the same shared object.

Answer (score 3):

Build the client as a [PIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code), with `-rdynamic`. Then you'll be able to `dlopen()` it and `dlsym()` its `main` symbol (`dlopen()` will do the `mmap`ing and `mprotect`ing for you, as you'll be able to see if you `strace` the program), after which you'll be able to run its `main` from within the address space of the host.

Example:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat > client.c <<EOF
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World!: from %ld\n", (long)getpid());
    return 0;
}
EOF

gcc -fpic -c client.c
gcc -pie -rdynamic -o client client.o

cat > host.c <<EOF
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello, I'm your host: %ld\n", (long)getpid());  ;

    void *client_hndl;
    typedef int main_t(int, char**);
    main_t *client_main;
    client_hndl = dlopen("./client",  RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!client_hndl){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        exit(1);
    }
    client_main = (main_t*)dlsym(client_hndl, "main");
    if (!client_main){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        exit(2);
    }
    return client_main(1, (char*[]){"client", 0});
}
EOF
gcc host.c -ldl
./client
echo =============
./a.out
```

Example output:

```
Hello, World!: from 14520
=============
Hello, I'm your host: 14521
Hello, World!: from 14521
```

Comment: Thanks, @PSkocik! This kinda works! But we need to use a shared-memory region. So the `client_hndl pointer`just points to the program? Can we copy this into a shared memory region that was created by us?a

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a solution to this GLIBC [feature request](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11767).

This feature request is 7 years old, and it's somewhat unlikely that anything will happen with it any time soon.

Your best bet is probably to do roughly what you are already doing (building a fully-static binary).

Your approach doesn't work because the executable you built *requires* to be loaded at the address it was linked at (visible in `readelf -l binfile` as the address of the first `PT_LOAD` segment. You would need to `mmap` your `binfile` there with `MAP_FIXED`, no other address will do.

You also need to read and decode the `Elf{32,64}_Ehdr` that is found at the beginning of the file to find *entry point* to jump to. You currently are jumping to the ELF header itself, but that header is not where the execution should start.